# Why cannot load actor image from TheMovieDatabase server even the links works on browser normaly?

Tags: c#, image, http, uwp, bitmapimage

This is really weird. This simple code can load any picture from net but not from TheMovieDatabase.

(`ActorImage` is the normal `Image` created in `xaml`)

Code is next:

```
string ImageUrl = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/dRLSoufWtc16F5fliK4ECIVs56p.jpg";
BitmapImage ActorBitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ImageUrl, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
ActorImage.Source = ActorBitmapImage;
```

Most weird thing is that if I open the browser the link works as it should to work.

Any idea what can cause the problem?

Comment: What happens if you change `UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute` to `UriKind.Absolute`?

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Does it throw an exception? Something else? What is the value of `actorBitmapImage.IsDownloading`?

Comment: Does this work `var ImageUrl = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/dRLSoufWtc16F5fliK4ECIVs56p.jpg";
            var bytes = new WebClient().DownloadDataTaskAsync(ImageUrl).Result;
            var actorBitmapImage = new BitmapImage {StreamSource = new MemoryStream(bytes)};`?

Comment: Thanks for answers but this problem still occur. I think that my Windows 10 or Visual Studio needs fresh start. I really don't see any fault in code and if I use `stream` to load bitmap to save it to locally on hd app just hangs without any warning ect. Also this code doesn't race any `exception` ect. Really odd... I even check firewall settings.

Comment: Reinstalled Windows ... Everything works now as it should to work. Still I cannot understand what was wrong with Win or Studio. **Anyway, problem solved.**